# Element bleed on left and right sides?

Tags: sass, susy-sass

I have a 5 column grid from Susy2 and Sass where the header and footer should be 100% the width of the body (for a full bleed effect) but their content should still use the grid's gutters.

Here's some sample markup:

```
<header>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</header>

<div id="main">
  <p>Quia blanditiis ...</p>
  <p>Nostrum iure reprehenderit...</p>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
  <p>Eveniet, aut, dolorum, adipisci dolor ...</p>
</div>

<footer>Hi mom</footer>
```

And here's the Sass and Susy that I've written:

```
@import "susy";

$susy: (
  columns: 5,
  gutters: 1/10,
  output: float,
  gutter-position: split,
  container: auto
);

body { @include container; }

header, footer {
  @include span(5);
  @include bleed();
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#main {
  @include span(3);
  outline: solid red 1px;
}

#sidebar {
  @include span(2);
  outline: solid yellow 1px;
}
```

Here's a Codepen demo: http://codepen.io/KatieK2/pen/xbdVbJ?editors=110

The problem is that header and footer have a small margin on their right sides, and they don't use any gutter spacing in the inside. How can I get them to be the full width of the container, and include the gutter as padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using split gutters and a full-width container, there is nothing you need to `bleed` over. Your header and footer will both flow to the edge by default, without any help from Susy. All you need to do is add gutters `inside` to get the content back on the grid.

```
header, footer {
  @include gutters(inside);
}
```

No other Susy code needed. Remove both the `span` and the `bleed`.

Comment: Hmmm, if I replace `@include bleed();` with `@include gutters(inside);`, then I get both margin and padding on the left of header and footer. If I include both bleed and gutters(inside), then there's no change. Could you be a little more explicit in the changes I should make? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, you want to remove all other susy code in that block — the `span` as well as the `bleed` mixins. All you want there is the padded gutter. I would generally avoid full-width `span`'s unless theres a real clear need for it. Elements are full-width by default, so why be redundant? :)

Comment: Ok, cool, that seems to do it. It seems for my example that I also have clear the floating on the footer element.